# C# How to check if git repository was updated

Tags: c#, git, commit

I would like to do a C# program that checks every x times if an online git repository (let's say a specific subdirectory) was updated and if so, download it to a specific folder. The thing is that I don't even know how to do the first step. I looked up the internet and I found a library called libgit2sharp. I don't know git very well but I saw that I can get the sha string of a commit with libgit2sharp so maybe that could help. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the latest commit hashes of each branch and store them. Check if the hashes have changed.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your *real* goal (e.g. maybe it's to perform some action whenever the monitored repository id updated)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the git 'fetch' command to check for new commits.

You can also use gitbash and parse the result it is quite simple.

see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch